# Cassandra user table data modelling

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0, datamodel

I am learning cassandra. I have to do basic user table modeling. Here waht I have did.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS users 
WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS users.date_type(
    month SMALLINT,
    day SMALLINT,
    year INT
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS users.phone_type(
    code INT,
    phone TEXT,
);

-- create user
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users.user(
    userid TIMEUUID,
    name TEXT,
    dob FROZEN<date_type>,
    username TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    phone FROZEN<phone_type>,
    email_verified BOOLEAN,
    phone_verified BOOLEAN,
    created_on TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

-- get user by username
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users.user_by_username(
    userid TIMEUUID,
    username TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

-- get user by user phone number
-- can have same number for more than one account
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users.user_by_phone(
    userid TIMEUUID,
    phone FROZEN<phone_type>,
    password TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (phone, userid)
);

-- get user by email
-- can have same email for more than one account
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users.user_by_email(
    userid TIMEUUID,
    email TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (email, userid)
);

-- user history
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users.user_history(
    userid TIMEUUID,
    name TEXT,
    dob FROZEN<date_type>,
    username TEXT,
    phone FROZEN<phone_type>,
    email TEXT,
    phone_verified BOOLEAN,
    email_verified BOOLEAN,
    action TEXT,
    date TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, date, action)
);
```

1. Is above table design valid as per cassandra data modeling?
2. Why because if I want to create an user, I have to insert in 5 tables
3. And if I want to update email, phone or password, first I have to delete entry in table then insert with updated values

Comment: in Cassandra everything starts by listing all queries, and then creating tables

Comment: Also, please ask only one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is above table design valid as per cassandra data modeling?

Yes it is valid table design as per Cassandra data modelling.

> Why because if I want to create an user, I have to insert in 5 tables

This is how you do in Cassandra, first you have queries which you want to cater and then design your tables according to them.

> And if I want to update email, phone or password, first I have to
> delete entry in table then insert with updated values

Just update the values, you do not need to delete them first. But make sure you update corresponding entries in each table.